# How to construct an object either from a const reference or temporary via forwarding template

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding, type-deduction

Consider this minimal example

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const T& t_)
        : t(t_)
    {
    }

    Foo(T&& t_)
        : t(std::move(t_))
    {
    }

    T t;
};

template <typename F>
Foo<F> makeFoo(F&& f)
{
    return Foo<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}

int main()
{
    class C
    {

    };

    C c;

    makeFoo(c);
}
```

MSVC 2017 fails with a redefinition error of Foo's ctor. Apparently T gets deduced to C& instead of the intended C. How exactly does that happen and how to modify the code so that it does what is inteded: either copy construct Foo::t from a const reference or move construct it from an r-value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
template <class F, class R = std::decay_t<F>>
Foo<R> makeFoo(F&& f)
{
  return Foo<R>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

that is a clean and simple way to solve your problem.

Decay is an appropriate way to convert a type into a type suitable for storing somewhere.  It does bad things with array types but otherwise does pretty much the right thing; your code doesn't work with array types anyhow.

---

The compiler error is due to reference collapsing rules.

```
 X          X&          X const&       X&&
 int        int&        int const&     int&&
 int&       int&        int&           int&
 int const  int const&  int const&     int const&&
 int&&      int&        int&           int&&
 int const& int const&  int const&     int const&
```

these may seem strange.

The first rule is that a const reference is a reference, but a reference to const is different.  You cannot qualify the "reference" part; you can only const-qualify the referred part.

When you  have `T=int&`, when you calculate `T const` or `const T`, you just get `int&`.

The second part has to do with how using r and l value references together work.  When you do `int& &&` or `int&& &` (which you cannot do directly; instead you do `T=int&` then `T&&` or `T=int&&` and `T&`), you always get an lvalue reference -- `T&`.  lvalue wins out over rvalue.

Then we add in the rules for how `T&&` types are deduced; if you pass a mutable lvalue of type `C`, you get `T=C&` in the call to `makeFoo`.

So you had:

```
template<F = C&>
Foo<C&> makeFoo( C& && f )
```

as your signature, aka

```
template<F = C&>
Foo<C&> makeFoo( C& f )
```

now we examine `Foo<C&>`.  It has two ctors:

```
Foo( C& const& )
Foo( C& && )
```

for the first one, `const` on a reference is discarded:

```
Foo( C& & )
Foo( C& && )
```

next, a reference to a reference is a reference, and lvalue references win out over rvalue references:

```
Foo( C& )
Foo( C& )
```

and there we go, two identical signature constructors.

TL;DR -- do the thing at the start of this answer.

Comment: Why does it fail in the first place? `Foo<C&>` should make the two constructors `Foo(const C&)` and `Foo(C&)` respectively, which are overloadable.

Comment: @0x499602D2 There, fully described

Answer (score 8):

In *C++17* you can simply write:

```
template <typename F>
auto makeFoo(F&& f)
{
    return Foo(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

because of *[class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)*.

---

In *C++14* you can write:

```
template <typename F>
auto makeFoo(F&& f)
{
    return Foo<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is that typename provided to class is reference in one case:

```
template <typename F>
Foo<F> makeFoo(F&& f)
{
    return Foo<F>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

becomes

```
template <>
Foo<C&> makeFoo(C& f)
{
    return Foo<C&>(std::forward<C&>(f));
}
```

You probably want some decay:

```
template <typename F>
Foo<std::decay_t<F>> makeFoo(F&& f)
{
    return Foo<std::decay_t<F>>(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of *reference collapsing*.

The `F&&` in your code is a *forwarding reference*, which means it can be either an *lvalue reference* or an *rvalue reference* depending on the type of the argument to which it binds.

In your case, if `F&&` binds to an argument of type `C&&` (an rvalue reference to `C`), `F` is simply deduced as `C`. However, if `F&&` binds to an argument of type `C&` (as in your example), the reference collapsing rules determine the type deduced for `F`:

```
T&  &  -> T&
T&  && -> T&
T&& &  -> T&
T&& && -> T&&
```

Thus, `F` is deduced as `C&`, since `C& &&` collapses to `C&`.

You can use [remove_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) to remove any reference from the deduced type:

```
remove_reference_t<C> -> C
remove_reference_t<C&> -> C
```

You will probably also want to use [`remove_cv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv) to remove any potential `const` (or `volatile`) qualifier:

```
remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<C>> -> C
remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<C&>> -> C
remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<C const>> -> C
remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<C const&>> -> C
```

In C++20, there is a combined [`remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) trait which can save some typing. However, many implementations just use [`decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), which does the same thing, but also turns array and function types into pointers, which may or may not be desirable depending on your use case (some parts of the standard library have switched from using `decay` to using `remove_cvref` in C++20).